# CPP function in IDA PRO

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, abi, ida, cracking

Trying to solve a crackme written in C++ for Windows on x86-64. https://www.crackmes.one/crackme/649a2ced33c5d43938913c6c

There are function calls that look like this in the IDA:

`call    __ZNSs4_Rep8_M_cloneERKSaIcEj ; std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&,uint)`

`call    __ZNSs4_Rep9_S_createEjjRKSaIcE ; std::string::_Rep::_S_create(uint,uint,std::allocator<char> const&)`

I want to understand what these functions do. Information on them is googled badly. It is very difficult to understand each such function in a disassembler.

Please tell me if there is a resource with a description of these functions. I think it has something to do with ABI.